# Set alarm in service and receive callback in the same service

Tags: android, android-service

My *ReminderService* uses the *AlarmManager* to inform the user about an upcoming event at a specific time. Is it possible that the AlarmManager informs the same service (ReminderService) or do I need to start another service to catch the pending intent? Until now this mechanism looks like this

```
public class ReminderService extends Service {

    // ...

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        // ..

        /* When the alarm goes off the NotifyService will be started. Is it possible to inform **this**
            service (ReminderService) and to handle the alarm? */
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, NotifyService.class);
        alarmIntent.putExtra(TodoTask.PARCELABLE_KEY, task);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = new Date(reminderTimeStamp*1000);
        calendar.setTime(date);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes u can. You just need to change this line:

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, NotifyService.class);
```

to this:

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, ReminderService.class);
```

that way the `ReminderService` will receive the intent with `TodoTask.PARCELABLE_KEY` inside this same method `public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)`

Remember that there no guarantee that this will be the same instance of the service. If the service you're running get killed by the system a new instance of it will be started to handle the intent.

Also remember all the sleep and doze mode stuff mentioned by Larry_Schiefer on his answer.

Comment: Great, but does this mean that I actually cannot store any data in my service, because it's always possible that the service gets killed. As I need to make some database requests, do I have to repeat them each time in onStartCommand?

Comment: Service receives `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` callbacks you can use to check status. So yes, if you need some data available u need to load/save it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same `Service` (or other component) to receive an alarm.  However, not that your alarm will not be guaranteed to be delivered on schedule when in low power.  Use a `WakefulReceiver` or your own combination of `BroadcastReceiver` and a wakelock to get your `Service` going.  See [this article](http://po.st/7UpipA) for more details on power state and alarms.

Also, note that starting with Android Marshmallow your wakelocks will be ignored if the device is in Doze mode.  There are other things you'll have to do to wake the device at a certain time when in Doze.